Kafka Service - Not releasing memory used
I have a Kafka set up on my server with below components

Zookeeper - Server 1
Kafka Broker - Server 2
Kafka Connect - Server 2
Kafka Streams - Server 2

And in kafka-server-start, my configuration is as below
if ["x$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS" = "x"]; then
    export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8G -Xms1G"

My server has 64 GB RAM.
When only Zookeeper / Kafka Broker / Kafka Connect is running - the Memory usage for Kafka broker service is more when records are being polled by Kafka Connect. But when the polling is complete - Still Kafka broker service uses same memory and memory doesn't reduce. As a result of this, my other applications running on the server is getting impacted as this application uses a lot of memory.
Memory usage is more than 28GB when Kafka connect pools records from view - around 100k in couple of hours.
How to reduce the memory once polling is complete or a better setting to avoid bottleneck on memory?

You can reduce memory by not running different JVM processes on the same machines. For example, Kafka doesn't require Zookeeper anymore, and Connect and Streams should be a separated cluster. Plus, you should not edit the start scripts
